# Color not transferring from Illustrator to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color-spaces

I have an Illustrator file and a Photoshop file, both are setup as RBG color spaces. But when I copy and past from Illustrator to Photoshop the color changes. For example #b74eab becomes #a6349b. I have never had any issues with copying and pasting between the two programs. Is there anyway to fix this>

Comment: Also, I have tried reseting my preferences for both applications and the problem still exists.

Comment: Are both apps using sync'ed color settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Color is a complex subject (hence "The Dress"), fortunately you seem to be suffering from an unwanted color conversion. If you go to *Edit > Color Settings* and ensure that these settings are set as follows...

- *Working Spaces*

  - The important thing here is that they match in both programs. This will have little effect after the rest of the settings are applied however, but it is still a good idea to "synchronize" these between the different apps you are using.
  - *RGB* :

    - **sRGB** (if you are working with images from a consumer level camera)
    - **Adobe RGB** (if you are working with images from a professional or "pro-sumer" camera, or if you intend to print the images)
  - *CMYK* : ***CMYK*** profiles are device dependent ...which means that you will have a specific one for the printer (or whatever) that is outputting your finished product. If you do not have a profile, or you are not sure who/what will be printing the file, just make sure the applications are using the same one (which will at least accomplish consistency, if not accuracy).
- **Preserve Embedded Profiles** : *enabled*
- *Profile Mismatches*

  - **Ask when opening** : *on*
  - **Ask when pasting** : *on*
- *Missing Profiles*

  - **Ask when opening** : *on*

This will prevent the application from converting the document's color space when it is imported, and force the app to let you know if there are any problems (if, for instance, the document doesn't have an imbedded profile).

*This is how your Color Settings should look:*

[image: Color Settings panel in Illustrator displaying the proper settings as outlined above]

Hopefully that helped you out. *If it did, mark it answered.* If you are still having issues, or you just want to know more about the nuts and bolts of color management in Creative Suite (it is a pretty vast subject), you can find more detailed info here at [Adobe's Creative Suite / Color Settings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WS6A727430-9717-42df-B578-C0AC705C54F0.html#WS83671E92-688A-4ad5-B98F-C32C478F2AD5) page.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My setting were way off and all the profile mismatch boxes were unchecked!

Answer (score 0):

You could check the color settings in both Photoshop and Illustrator to see if they have the same working space. If you are pasting from sRGB to say AdobeRGB, you are pasting between 2 different color spaces. That might cause what you are seeing, depending on the color.